# CORS error while calling the unofficial Airbnb API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, cors

I have been trying to use the Airbnb API from [this link](http://airbnbapi.org/). I know it is not an official API, but I really need to use it in my website. But I am getting
CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error and I cannot call the API. When I tried from hurl.it it was working absolutely fine.

But now I am not sure how do I correct this? I am using ruby on rails on backend and jQuery Ajax to call the API. My Ajax code call is below. I am creating an empty listing as a host in Airbnb from this code.

```
$("#submit_apartments").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.airbnb.com/v1/listings/create?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token": "myAuthToken"
    },
    data: {
      room_type_category: "private_room",
      property_type_id: 2,
      bathrooms: 1,
      person_capacity: 1,
      beds: 1,
      bedrooms: 1,
      city: "Sunnyvale, California, US"
    },
    success: function() {
     console.log("Sucess");
    },
    error: function(xhr,err){
      console.log("Error!!!");
     }
   });  
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the Airbnb API from client-side JavaScript in a web app, you’ll either need to set up your own CORS proxy using code from https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors or similar, or you can send your request through an open CORS proxy such as https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.airbnb.com/v1/listings/create?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty",
  …
}
```

The CORS proxy will send the request to the Airbnb API endpoint and then when it gets a response from Airbnb, it will add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and all other needed CORS header to the response it passes on to the browser and that the browser sees.

However, note that you probably really don’t want to use a third-party open proxy to send requests to any logged-in endpoint that requires a `X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token` access token—because the owner of proxy would be able to see your `X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token` value and reuse it.

So you really should set up your own proxy instead, using https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors or such.

Making the request through a proxy like that is the only way that will work, because the Airbnb API itself doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header required by the CORS protocol, and also doesn’t seem to support the alternative of allowing you to specify a callback name so that you can get JSONP-formatted responses.

So that means there’s no way to call the Airbnb API directly from client-side JavaScript running in a web app, because the browser won’t allow your client-side JS code to access the response at all.

To confirm that, try a request to any endpoint URL for its API and look at the response headers:

```
curl -i -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
  "https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty"
```

Response headers you’ll get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.7.12
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Status: 200 OK
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https:; connect-src 'self' https: ws://localhost.airbnb.com:8888 http:; font-src 'self' data: *.muscache.com fonts.gstatic.com use.typekit.net; frame-src *; img-src 'self' https: http: data:; media-src 'self' https:; object-src 'self' https:; script-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http:; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' http:; report-uri /tracking/csp?action=index&controller=v2&req_uuid=cd9b2eb5-5014-4587-8f6b-144c800b6d7b&version=b11f4837d2aaab4f25311eaabfd788770abc5557;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
ETag: W/"1dc7df77adc42a864c6a7a6806a68a6f"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400; includeSubdomains
Date: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:31:08 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
```

Notice there’s no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header there.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more CORS info.